# Converting 301 redirects into RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

After building a new site I have a couple of redirects in my htaccess to redirect the users to the right page for SEO reasons.

It are all 301 redirects in 1 of this format:

For pages

`Redirect 301 /page.html /new-page`

For product

`Redirect 301 /webshop/category-name/subcategory-name/detail/123/product-name.html /product/product-name`

subcategory is optional, not all products are in an subcategory, but they have at least 1 category. 123 is an product id, which is different on all products.

For category

`Redirect 301 /webshop/category-name/subcategory-name /category/category-name`

subcategory is optional.

That works fine, but since this website is reachable by 2 domains (dutch and english site) these redirect must only work when the domain is `dutchdomain` and `englishdomain`.

So, I read about the rewriteEngine, the rewriteCond and rewriteRule and tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dutchdomain\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule /faq.html /faq/ [L,R=302]
```

But that isn't working. How can I get this working with the domain condition?
Is there a way to do that with an regular expresion, so that I have only a few lines instead a the 1668 lines I have now?

With the regex `webshop (*.+\)\` I replaced the url's from the old site sitemap for the products. The url's for the pages and the categories's I replaced manually.

Comment: Can you formulate your requirements in an input and output format, because I see a lot of questions scattered?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.dutchdomain\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule /faq.html /faq/ [L,R=302]` looks OK except for one thing the leading slash in rewrite pattern doesn't work on htaccess context (works only on server config or virtual host context) . So you need it remove it. Change your `/faq.html` to `faq.html` or `^faq.html` to match exactly this URI.

Comment: _Maybe_ `RewriteRule ^/?(.+).html /$1 [L,R=302]` is what you are looking for, but you certainly have read that endless times when reading about the rewriting module... Your question is unclear, so no one is able to give a clear answer...